# Select from two tables Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I use Laravels many to many relations. I have 2 tables `projects` and `groups` and pivot table `project_group`

Now I can do something like this:

```
$groups = \App\Project::findOrFail(Auth::user() -> id)->groups()->where('adminid','=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

It will return just Groups...Like this:

```
Design
SEO
```

But I need to return like this:

```
Design(Project2,Project3)
SEO(Porject1)
```

So for each loop I need to get group and all project linked to that group.

Here is my relation into Project modul:

```
public function groups(){
    return $this ->belongsToMany('App\Group','project_group')->withPivot('admin_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the inverse of the relationship in your Group model.

```
public function projects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project','project_group')->withPivot('admin_id');
}
```

And then, use it in your eloquent query.

```
$groups = Group::with('projects')->get();
```

You'll be able to loop through your groups and in each group get all projects.

```
foreach($groups as $group) {
  foreach($group->projects as $project){
    //your project
  }
}
```

I don't really understand the usage of `Auth::user() -> id` but if you only want project where the current user is admin you can use a condition in the with function.

```
$groups = Group::with(['projects' => function($query) {
  $query->where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)
}])->get();
```

Comment: `Auth::user()->id` returns the `id` of the currently logged-in user. In Laravel 5, there's a middleware that checks if a user is logged in, and you can access that record (fields and relationships) using `Auth::user()`.